# I want to let people sign into my site with a google account

Tags: api

ok i am planning on using the OpenID and i've read googles documentation and see other tutorials on how to do it. They all use this link https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud but that link throws a 400 error. This is no longer in use?

edit: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

edit I ended up going with OAuth 2.0

Comment: Incorrect link mate.  @MichaelKrelin provides the correct link in his answer.

Comment: Check the headers and see if it gives any sort of better explanation.  Just because Google's page says that's all they know doesn't mean it's actually all they know (I hate that page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since im using codeigniter for this project i ended up going with http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id ?

Comment: yes sorry. Im using the lightopenid library. maybe i should just read more. something just doesnt seem correct

Comment: since im using codeigniter for this project i ended up going with http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/